# Compare two unbalanced contingency tables in r

Tags: r, contingency-tables, frequency

I have two df that I convert to contingency tables, each df identifies two sets of survey questions results in two different months.

The number of rows of the dfs is different, meaning that surveys got different amounts of responses.

Each dataframe contains the same unique values (4 different unique values per column) - appearing with different frequencies.

I want to make two mosaic plots to compare the two different months - but I assume the two contingency tables are not comparable.

Here how I calculate my contingency tables:

```
# df month 1
df_1 <- structure(list(body = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label =c("athletic ", "chubby ", "normal", "slim"), class = "factor"), hair = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("black", "blonde", "brunette","red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("body", "hair"), class ="data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, -5L))


#compute contingency table
cont_table_1 <- xtabs(~df_1$body + df_1$hair, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)

# df month 2
df_2 <- structure(list(body = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label =    c("athletic ","chubby ", "normal", "slim"), class = "factor"), hair = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("black", "blonde", "brunette", "red"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("body", "hair"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

#compute contingency table  
cont_table_2 <- xtabs(~df_2$body + df_2$hair, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
```

How to approach this problem?

Comment: It appears you have a survey with two items (hair type and body type), with 5 responders in the first month and 6 responders in the second month. Is this correct? What is your research question or null hypothesis?

Comment: My request question is: is there any correlation between hair colour and body type (within the same month)? is this correlation changing month by month? My methodology is to use a mosaic plot of the different contingency tables for each month. Given that the number of responders varies per month, I ask : do I need to somehow balance those contingency tables?

Comment: But do you have a total of only 11 observations or do you have much more data than that?

Comment: This is just a small example. I have 287, 3916 and 1589 observations for three consecutive months.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very old technique to standardize a contingency table, see e.g. Yule 1912. You could use that technique to standardize your counts and feed those to your favorite graphics program to make the graph you like.

Yule, U. (1912) On the methods of measuring association between two attributes, *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society*, 75(6): 579-652. 
[link](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2340126)